# Several SQL syntax questions

Tags: syntax

I have several small questions and I wrote some simple examples to clarify them:

1. Will a nested aggregate take one value from from all groups? Like the minimal maximum of all groups? or the minimum count?

   ```
   Select x, min(max(z))
   From y
   Group by x
   ```

   On the same note, is there any merit in doing the following to get the minimal count from all groups, or the second line is unnecessary?

   ```
   select x, min(count(*))
   select x, count(*)
   From y
   Group by x
   ```

   If both are invalid, how would you do a query on all groups like taking the minimum of all maximums in each group?
2. Can you do a query inside a "from"?

   ```
   Select x 
   From y natural inner join (select z AS y
                              from foo)
   ```
3. Is it allowed to do `from *` after a `group by`?

   ```
   Select x
   From y
   Group by x
   Having avg(x) > (select *
                    from *
                    where x > 1)
   ```

   and if not, how would you do a query on each group after the `group by`?

Note: this isn't some live version of SQL server, just old theoretical SQL.

Comment: The first query is invalid - you can't nest aggregates like that. The second one under 1) is also invalid - you can't have two `select` keywords without using a derived table or a sub-query. And 3) is a clear no.

Comment: So what is the proper way to do a query on all groups like taking the minimum from all maximums? And is it possible to have a predicate for each group after `group by`? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The first query (`Select x, min(max(z))
From y
Group by x`) is not valid SQL but it runs in Oracle (and only there) without error.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: that will not run with Oracle. You can only nest aggregates if you don't select additional columns. e.g. `select min(max(z)) from y group by x` does indeed work in Oracle, but not the query shown

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah yes, true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re 1)

With standard SQL the only way to do that is:

```
select min(cnt)
from (
  select x, count(*) as cnt
  from y
  group by x
) t
```

re 2)

yes you can join to a query, but you need to give the derived table an alias

```
Select x 
From y 
  natural join (select z AS y
                from foo) as t;
```

That assumes that the table `y` **also** has a column `y` - otherwise there wouldn't be two identical columns that the natural join could use.

But in general you should avoid the natural join. Use an explicit join instead:

```
select x 
from y 
  join (select z AS y
       from foo
  ) as t on t.y = y.id;
```

re 3)

No, `from *` is never allowed. But I have no clue what you intend to do with that. The sub-select used with `>` (or `<` or `=`) **has** to return exactly one row and exactly one column so you would need something like:

```
Select x
From y
Group by x
Having avg(x) > (select count(*) -- no idea what you would want to do here
                 from y
                 where x > 1);
```

If the subselect returns more then one *row* you would need to use `ANY`

```
Select x
From y
Group by x
Having avg(x) > ANY (select x -- still only ONE column allowed
                     from y
                     where x > 1);
```

Comment: Not use natural join? Why? It makes things a lot more simple.

Comment: @kuhaku: natural join just looks at column _names_ and it picks the first ones that match. You have no control over it. If you are learning SQL, believe me: stay away from it.

Comment: The first query can also be written without derived table: `select count(*) as cnt
  from y group by x order by cnt desc fetch first 1 row only;`

Comment: About the natural join: You can `natural join` two tables even if they have no common column. It becomes a `cross join`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: even worse then ;)